# How to format the output data in a parent/child relationship tree model?

Tags: python

I have the following code which will look for the COMPONENT that we want to get information for, and then it will find the COMPONENT’s child Component attribute values (if there are any) and then find it’s child component values (so it goes on like a recursion).

For example, we begin searching for ‘x123’. In ‘x123’ XML file, we see that it has two child components values: ‘x454’ and ‘x762’. I then used recursion to find the child component values for ‘x454’ and ‘x762’. Since there are no component values found in ‘x454’ and ‘x762’ XML files, I print `“No Component values found in x454” “No Component values found in x762”`.

This is the output of the current code:

```
Searching for x123:
Child Component ID:x454
Searching for x454:
No Component values found in x454
Child Component ID:x762
Searching for x762:
No Component values found in x762
```

This output is misleading visually because, the `“Child Component ID:x762”` is not the child of x454. It is the child of `x123`. I am not sure how to make the change in the code to reflect this issue? Is there something I missed in the For loop? Is there a way for me to format the code to show it in a hierarchy structure, something like below?

This is how the correct output should look like:

```
Searching for x123:
    Child Component ID:x454
        Searching for x454:
            No Component values found in x454
    Child Component ID:x762
        Searching for x762:
            No Component values found in x762
```

XML

```xml
<TestHomePage ID="x123" Name="Some Home page">
<Title type="string" UID="...." label="Title">Highlights</Title>
<Book Type="List" Name="BottomSection" UID=".......">
    <Book Type="Component" Name="Tab" **Component="x454"** UID="........."/>
    <Book Type="Component" Name="Tab" **Component="x762"** UID="......."/>
</Book>
</TestHomePage>



<TestCompOne ID="x454" Name="Some Component Name">
<Title type="string" UID="...." label="Title">Test Comp</Title>
<Book Type="Insert" Name="SideSection" UID="......."/>
<Count type="enumeration" UID=".....">1</Count>
<Display type="enumeration" UID=".......">Title</Display>
</TestCompOne>


<TestCompTwo ID="x762" Name="Some Component Name">
<Title type="string" UID="...." label="Title">Test Comp</Title>
<Book Type="Insert" Name="SideSection" UID="......."/>
<Count type="enumeration" UID=".....">1</Count>
<Display type="enumeration" UID=".......">Title</Display>
</TestCompTwo>
```

Code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import datetime
import os
import csv
import re
import glob

temp_storage = {}
def handlingXML(COMPONENT, filepath=".."):
    print(f"Searching for {COMPONENT}:")
    for path in glob.glob(os.path.join(filepath,"x*.xml")):
        doc = temp_storage.setdefault(path, ET.parse(path).getroot())
        
        if(doc.get("ID")== COMPONENT):
            thePlace = doc.findall('.//Book[@Type="Component"]')
            if len(thePlace) == 0:
                print("No Component values found in " + COMPONENT)
            else:
                for comp_elem in thePlace:
                    comp_uniqueID = comp_elem.get("Component")

                    if comp_uniqueID != "":
                        print(f" Child Component ID:{comp_uniqueID}")
                        handlingXML(comp_uniqueID, filepath=filepath)

handlingXML('x123', filepath=r"D:/../../../../")
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you are trying to do is add nesting, a simple string format can provide the results you want. You just need to allow your function to keep track of a nesting level and increment it on every recursion. I refactored your code a little to make it a bit more efficient and clean.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import glob, os


def comp_tree(comp:str, path:str) -> None:
    #only do this once - instead of on every recursion
    path = os.path.join(path, "x*.xml")
    docs = {path:ET.parse(path).getroot() for path in glob.glob(path)}
    spc  = '    '
        
    #encapsulate recursion
    def parse(comp:str, n:int) -> None:
        #format nest level
        nest = spc*n  
        print(f'{nest}Searching for {comp}:')
        
        #find doc
        for doc in docs.values():
            if doc.get("ID") == comp:
                break
        else: 
            print(f'{nest}No document was found containing ID="{comp}"')
            return
        
        #we are finding children within a parent
        #so we have to format next nest level
        n   += 1
        nest = spc*n
        
        #find components, if available      
        if complist := doc.findall('.//Book[@Type="Component"]'):
            for node in complist:
                if cid := node.get("Component"):
                    print(f'{nest}Child Component ID: {cid}')
                    parse(cid, n+1)
        else:
            print(f'{nest}No Component values found in {comp}')
                
    #first call                
    parse(comp, 0)


comp_tree('x123', r"D:/../../../../")
```

output:

```
Searching for x123:
    Child Component ID: x454
        Searching for x454:
            No Component values found in x454
    Child Component ID: x762
        Searching for x762:
            No Component values found in x762
```